# Web Deploy not recognizing files

Tags: deployment, webmatrix

Deploying to server on my local network using web deploy. All validation runs correctly, but when Publish summary screen comes up there are no files to add to the website, However the MSSQL connection string shows up to add. Am I missing something simple in the server configuration? Any leads as too what might be the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try following the steps described [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1016/when-publishing-a-site-from-webmatrix-using-the-ftp-protocol-some-files-are-not-listed-in-the-publish-preview-dialog/) in learn.iis.net website.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be prompted to add a remote SQL Server connection string if you choose to publish your site's databases and your site is using a SQL Server database. You'll have to get the SQL Server connection string from your web hosting provider and save it in the Publish Settings dialog, or choose not to publish the database from your site.